# Open a file saved on a team place with batch

Tags: batch

I would like to open a excel file saved on an intranet teamplace using a batch file.

The problem that i found is that the link for the file

https://teamplace.volvo.com/sites/3p-AusQuality/GTT%20Australia%20Quality%20Meeting/Document%20Library/1/QJ/QJ%201-4257722781%20Air%20compressor%20fitting%20leaks/Copy%20of%20QWB%20Air%20intake%20pipes%20testxlsx.xlsx

uses %20 as spacer and once the batch runs the link its removes the %2 and the link does not work:

https://teamplace.volvo.com/sites/3p-AusQuality/GTT0Australia0Quality0Meeting/Document0Library/1/QJ/QJ01-42577227810Air0compressor0fitting0leaks/Copy0of0QWB0Air0intake0pipes0testxlsx.xlsx

Comment: Use `"`s or escape the `%`s with `^`

Answer (score 0):

The original link *could* work directly from `cmd` command window (under further particular conditions), e.g. as follows:

```
start "" iexplore https://teamplace.volvo.com/sites/3p-AusQuality/GTT%20Australia%20Quality%20Meeting/Document%20Library/1/QJ/QJ%201-4257722781%20Air%20compressor%20fitting%20leaks/Copy%20of%20QWB%20Air%20intake%20pipes%20testxlsx.xlsx
```

However, `%` sign followed by a cipher has special meaning in a batch script, see `call /?` or [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Use either spaces instead `%20` **and** enclose the link in a pair of `"` double quotes

```
start "" iexplore "https://teamplace.volvo.com/sites/3p-AusQuality/GTT Australia Quality Meeting/Document Library/1/QJ/QJ 1-4257722781 Air compressor fitting leaks/Copy of QWB Air intake pipes testxlsx.xlsx"
```

or [double all the `%` signs to escape theirs special meaning](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) and treat them literally as follows:

```
start "" iexplore "https://teamplace.volvo.com/sites/3p-AusQuality/GTT%%20Australia%%20Quality%%20Meeting/Document%%20Library/1/QJ/QJ%%201-4257722781%%20Air%%20compressor%%20fitting%%20leaks/Copy%%20of%%20QWB%%20Air%%20intake%%20pipes%%20testxlsx.xlsx"
```